# Toggle paragraph display using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Can someone tell me why the JavaScript code below is returning an undefined error when I click on the button the second time?

When clicked the first time, it will reveal the text in the h3 element, and the button's inner.text will change. However, when I click it again, I get the undefined error.

I look in the DOM and see that the class name has changed to "reveal" after the first click and it does. I assumed on the second click, when the class name was changed to "reveal", the conditional statement would jump to the "else" portion and change the class back to "hide" and button text back in order to hide the h3 text again. However, I get the "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of undefined".

```
<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <div id="button-div">
        <button id="button">Click to Reveal</button>
    </div>
    <h3 class="hide">Text</h3>
    <h2>subtext</h2>

  </header>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

And the JS:

```
var button = document.getElementById("button");
var textHide = document.getElementsByClassName("hide");

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (textHide[0].className === "hide") {
      textHide[0].className = "reveal";
      button.innertext = "Click to Hide";
    } else {
      textHide[0].className = "hide";
      button.innertext = "Click to Reveal";  
    }
    console.log("click");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of undefined" because there is no element with class name 'hide'on second click.

```
var button = document.getElementById("button");
var textHide = document.getElementsByTagName("h3");

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (textHide[0].className == "hide") {
      textHide[0].className = "reveal";
      button.innertext = "Click to Hide";
    } else {
      textHide[0].className = "hide";
      button.innertext = "Click to Reveal";  
    }
    console.log("click");
});
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/5pq0hbye/

Comment: Thanks, this required the least amount of editing! Simple fix. Makes sense now. I woke up this AM and realized the error, but wasn't sure how to fix it. I'm new to JS so I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

It happens because `getElementsByClassName` works in a *live* manner. So, when you change the `className` from `hide` to `none`, the object `textHide` is also updated, and then there are no more elements with the `hide` CSS class in your page.

You can avoid that behavior by using `querySelectorAll`:

```
var textHide = document.querySelectorAll(".hide");
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you hide the element, you're emptying `document.getElementsByClassName("hide")` because it's a [live](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) NodeList - ie it gets updated every time class names get updated.  By resetting the class name, you're removing the `hide` class.

```
var button = document.getElementById("button");
var textHide = document.getElementsByClassName("toHide");

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (textHide[0].classList.contains('hide')) {
      textHide[0].classList.remove("hide");
      button.innertext = "Click to Hide";
    } else {
      textHide[0].classList.add("hide");
      button.innertext = "Click to Reveal";  
    }
    console.log("click");
});
```

Update your class in the HTML accordingly to `toHide hide` instead of `hide` so that you have a reference to get the element by and it initializes hidden.  Alternatively, you could use an ID or different class name.